# auto resize label in custom cell during delete

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Im making on an ios app and currently working to get cell deletion from a tableview working. I have the ios swipe to delete working with the default red button appearing in from the right to delete the cell. all working wonderfully. But the problem im having is that i cant get the 2 uilabels that are within the custom cell to autoresize over when the red button moves in. so the red button is currently covering up one of the labels . i have been trying afew things with no luck so far.

```
primaryLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
primaryLabel.bounds = primaryLabel.frame; //incase auto resize was using bounds instead of frame
cell.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
primaryLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;//tried various options in here
```

Im hoping to get a solution to this through code rather then with IB on this particuliar problem. So any help would be appreciated

[image]

as requested screenshot. the D is start of second label that isnt autosizing with the rest

Comment: Can u provide some screen shot for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding the labels via code, make sure you are adding them to the cell's `contentView` and not directly as subviews of the cell. The content view is resized when the cell enters editing mode, the main cell is not.